# Is C++ template mechanism is just a type builder function?

Tags: c++, templates, programming-languages, language-theory

I just started to think on the subject. Every C++ template can be replaced with a "normal" function that returns a class (or function) object? Normal means compile-time program.

So I want to replace the template instantiation in C++ compiling with "normal functions (means compile time programs that works on compiler parse tree or something similar)", and I don't want to use the declerative syntax.

Do you think that with the following idea we can replace the whole template mechanism in C++?  Do you think that this way result an easier to understand templating? The question a little bit theoretical I know, but I don't know where is the best place to discuss this kink of question.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
  int foo();
  bool bar;
  T data;
};

#if 0
class A(typename T) // class bulder after "("
{
  class ret;          // class object can only declared in class builder
  ret.name = "whatever_compile_time_string";
  ret += body         // body is a class builder member with class declaration syntax
         {
           body();    // constructor
           ~body();   // destructor
           int foo(); // method
           bool bar;  // member
         };
  ret += member(T, "data"); // "inject" a templated member

  return ret;
}
#endif


int main()
{
  A<int> a;
#if 0
  // create a new class
  typedef new class A(int) AInt;
  // or
  typedef new class A(int); // in this case class.name must be an initialized thing
#endif
}
```

Comment: Templates are indeed a form of compile-time code generation. Everything you can do with a template could also be done by spelling out the code explicitly.

Comment: Your example completely ignores the entire machinery of specialization, argument deduction and overload resolution, which is crucial to the importance of templates.

Comment: I’m not sure what the question here is. Yes, templates are metafunctions which return types. But beyond that … what do you want to know?

Comment: I think, I can update my example with specialization (with class builder function overload), argument deduction (ret.type or something syntax) and I started think on overload resolution

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I want to know that this approach 1. almost the same as templating system that we have now, 2. this approach is easier to understand

Comment: Your approach is not similar enough to templates as they currently are. Consider for instance explicit template specializations.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant: I considered this as well, but eventually concluded that C++ templates are _far_ easier to make run fast, and this method, though more flexible, makes programs run very slow indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. What you are describing is a macro system. The C preprocessor provides a weak form of macros, but, in the general case, macros are nothing more or less than programs to write source code (taking source code as input), executed at compile time.

Now, the theory of macros turns out to be somewhat complicated. Obviously, you can do whatever you want with any macro system that lets you execute code at compile time, but a lot of work has gone into making it so that doing the right thing is easy. (In particular, it really helps to have syntax quotation construct that you can interpolate into.)

With a powerful macro system, many statements that were previously built into the language can instead be user-defined, or included in the standard library.

If you're interested in the subject, take a look at Scheme, and especially the Racket programming language. Racket has a very small core, and almost all of the language that the user experiences is built out of macros.

Answer (score 2):

No. One of the main things about templates is that they provide statically inferred typesafe polymorphism.

By definition, you can't do that at runtime. If you want to move everything to runtime, don't use C++, use something optimised for late binding.

Update: If you're talking a function that is run at compile-time, then (a) you will need your compiler to interpret C++ (if you want to write it in C++), and you lose the benefits of the declarative, functional language that is templates. I don't see the benefit.

Comment: I wrote in the question that "Normal means compile-time program."

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant Great. You still can't perform type inference at compile time with a function.

Comment: I want to introduce a compile-time-function like thing, that not run on runtime but in compile time. I want replace the template instantiation phase with these kind of "functions"

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant So, it's (a) not normal, in that it would run at compile time; and (b) require the function writer to manually code the type-inference procedure that templates perform? What's the benefit here?

Comment: I want to create classes with easier syntax. For example I have a compile time string-type pair array and I want crate a class with self serialization capability for XML mapping.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant Your approach doesn't seem to provide any type inference. If you want to go ahead and add this as a language extension, why not just go ahead and do it?

Comment: I want it as a language extension to replace the declarative template syntax. It is an idea and i want some feedback. I want to manipulate (and ceate) the classes in compile time with an easy syntax.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant my feedback: it is a bad idea and unlikely that you will be able to implement all template functionality. Plus template syntax is easy, it just takes some learning and practice.

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks for your feedback. I think the template syntax a bit complicated and hard to understand. I wrote a compile time SQL engine and it was a little bit hard. link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/c-template-meta-sql

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant That's a tiny amount of code. For it to do anything like manipulate or generate SQL is awesome. Seriously, if you think your syntax is easier, the first thing to do is to build a prototype extension to e.g. g++.

Comment: @Marcin: I want to wrote an XML bind program (that maps XML data structures to normal classes, like (http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/), but I think it is impossible with template techniques, so I wrote a program that generate C++ code. And I go ahead and I started to think a language that is in the C++ standard. I want compile time maps, compile time for, while loops, and so on.. Maybe the program input can be a file... The program runs, generate classes from XML, just like in template instantiation.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant given that templates are turing-complete (subject to stack depth restrictions in the compiler), it will definitely be possible. While I don't think that what you want to do is an improvement, maybe you will prefer it.

Comment: @Marcin: TM programming is a turning complete thing, but this does not mean that you can add methods, members to a class with an arbitrary name.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant You'd be surprised what can be done, but yes.

Comment: @Marcin, the benefits are obvious. When a macro language can interact with the host/target language, and when there is at least some form of a reflection is available, you can easily automate many cases of boilerplate code generation. E.g., you can fetch the data from a database or a configuration file and generate wrapper code. And the most powerful thing - you can parse arbitrary complex strings and compile them in place. Imagine, say, a static regexp compiler - something not quite possible with the current C++ templates.

Comment: @SK-logic Just because there are benefits, it does not follow that such a mechanism would be a complete replacement for templates, unless it also subsumed all current template functionality. It's difficult to see how a procedural replacement could do that, but conceivable that an extension to the template system might be able to.

Comment: @Marcin, of course a procedural template mechanism will be capable of doing all the same stuff as the current one. It will just be more clumsy and verbose.

Comment: @SK-logic Will it be able to perform type-inference? That's not a given.

Comment: @Marcin, why not? There must be a decent degree of reflection available, otherwise there is no point in the whole thing. So, it should be possible to query about types in the AST transformer functions.

Comment: @SK-logic Right, of course it can do everything, if you assume all relevant features. However, that's a much bigger project if you want to build a full-featured reflective system from the ground up.

Comment: @Marcin, not at all, I've done this for plain C with surprisingly little effort.

Comment: @SK-logic I can't comment on specific, but unpresented examples. You could tell me that you have an angelic non-deterministic turing machine, but I can't comment on it if I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways used by C programmers to achieve similar effects like templates in C++. However I do not see any beneficial from using these ways instead of templates in C++. But if you think templates are hard to understand, then look at these:

### By using macros:

```
// N: typename, T: used type
#define MAKE_A(N, T)  class N { \
public: N(){} ~N(){}  bool flag; T data; }

MAKE_A(AInt, int);
MAKE_A(AFloat, float);
```

### By using extra implementation-header files:

file: A.h (do not place inclusion guards):

```
// A_NAME: typename, A_TYPE: used type
class A_NAME { 
public: 
    A_NAME(){} 
    ~A_NAME(){}  
    bool flag; 
    A_TYPE data; 
};
```

Usage:

```
#define A_NAME AInt
#define A_TYPE int
#include "A.h"
#undef A_NAME
#undef A_TYPE 

#define A_NAME AFloat
#define A_TYPE float
#include "A.h"
#undef A_NAME
#undef A_TYPE
```

Comment: I know the Boost.PP (http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html) but with this technique very hard to write a for loop or a simple if then construct. I want to achieve a type safe meta class framework in C++, just like in python: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta/index.html

Comment: Maybe I am too C++ oriented ;) but C++ templates are easier for me than this python way. Just matter of taste. However I doubt you force C++ standard folks to introduce this change. You can try - start with `comp.std.c++` group.

Comment: THX, I will think it over a little bit and I will write it there

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of BOOST.PP over templates is that programs generated with
BOOST.PP compile faster than equivalent programs using templates, at
least according to this post to the [boost devel list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/189925).

Even with the improved speed of gcc using hashes instead of linear
lookup, I believe using BOOST.PP is still faster, I guess because of
the limitations mentioned by Walter Bright in the referenced post.